# jquery image rotator (Pass image in JS only)

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation, slider

I am trying to build all JQuery image rotator.

I am aware of simple jquery sliders/rotators, but i want to pass image file inside JS only.

I DON'T want to do this

```
 <div id="slider">
    <div class="content"><p>blah</p></div>
    <div class="content"><p>blah</p></div>
    <div class="content"><p>blah</p></div>
</div>
```

For example I have this simple text rotator. Now i want to replace TEXT with IMAGE file.

My text rotator is like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {$.fn.cycle = function(arr, options) {
    var settings = {
        'delay': 2000,
        'transitionDuration': 500,
        'transitionEasing': 'swing'
    };

    if (options) $.extend(settings, options);

    return this.each(function(ndx, el) {
        $(el).data('cycle:i', 0);
        setInterval(function(el, settings, arr) {
            $(el).fadeOut(settings['transitionDuration'], settings['transitionEasing'], function() {
                var t = $(this);
                var i = t.data('cycle:i');
                i = i == arr.length - 1 ? 0 : i+1;
                t.data('cycle:i', i)
                    .html(arr[i])
                    .fadeIn(settings['transitionDuration'], settings['transitionEasing']);
                });
        }, settings['delay'], el, settings, arr);
    });
};
```

Calling it like

```
$('#textcontainer').cycle(['onetext', 'twotext', 'threetext', 'fourtext']);
```

Now i want to pass images here

```
$('#imagecontainer').cycle(['one.png', 'two.png', 'three.png', 'four.png']);
```

What modifications are required in JS ?

UPDATE :

After suggestion from Chaos , i updated code..
here is jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/n5XLf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line of code that's writing the text to the DOM is

```
 .html(arr[i])
```

You just need to switch that to

```
 .html('<img src="' + arr[i] + '"/>')
```

and that will load the image in to the container (assuming the input array is an array of actual image locations)

Comment: Thanks..i just did that.images tarted blinking but it is not changing to another..

Comment: i did it like this $('#logorotate').imagecycle(['logo1.png', 'logo2.png']);

Comment: Hi Chaos..i added jsfiddle..can you please verify ?

Comment: Hi Vatsal, I had a look at the link you provided. The reason it's blinking is because there are two elements in your image array but they both point to the same picture. It looks like it's blinking because it's fading in then out of essentially the same picture. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yes. I figured that out..silly mistake !..thanks a lot for looking at it..really appreciate it.